# Using Jetpack Compose Bottom Sheet to achieve the Snapchat's Profile Screen Bottom Sheet

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, bottom-sheet

I am creating a profile screen similar to Snapchat's profile screen, which includes a background profile picture and a bottom sheet displaying the name and other details. I have implemented the screen and bottom sheet in two different ways. Here are the code snippets:

1. Using ModalBottomSheet:

```
@Composable
fun UserScreen() {
val modalBottomSheet = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        UserImageView()
    
    }
    
    BottomSheet(modalBottomSheet)

}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun BottomSheet(showModalBottomSheet: MutableState\<Boolean\>) {
rememberCoroutineScope()

    ModalBottomSheet(
        onDismissRequest = { showModalBottomSheet.value = true }
    ) {
        HeadingTextComponent(value = stringResource(id = R.string.username))
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
        CardComponent()
    
        LazyColumn(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            items(50) { index ->
                Text(
                    text = "Item $index",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(16.dp)
                )
            }
        }
    }

}
```

[Output of ModalBottomSheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIpin.jpg)
However, this approach had one issue: swiping down the bottom sheet would minimize it, which is not the desired behavior. So, I explored another approach:

2. Using BottomSheetScaffold:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun UserScreen() {
Column(
modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
) {
MyBottomSheet()
}
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun MyBottomSheet() {
BottomSheetScaffold(
sheetContent = {
HeadingTextComponent(value = stringResource(id = R.string.username))
LazyColumn(
modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
) {
items(50) { index -\>
Text(
text = "Item $index",
modifier = Modifier
.fillMaxWidth()
.padding(16.dp)
)
}
}
},
sheetPeekHeight = 600.dp
) {

        UserImageView()
    
    }

}
```

[Output of BottomSheetScaffold](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mHLs.jpg)
I appreciate this approach because it allows me to set the sheetPeekHeight to 600.dp, preventing it from collapsing. However, there are a few issues that need to be addressed:

- When the bottom sheet is fully expanded, the rounded corners are still visible.
- The bottom sheet does not overlap with the notification bar, resulting in the display of the bottom sheet icon and rounded corners.
- Additionally, when the sheet is fully expanded and you forcefully swipe it, the sheet detaches temporarily. This issue occurs in both sets of codes.

Desired behavior:

- The bottom sheet should have a specific initial height.
- The sheet should not collapse when clicking the scrim or swiping down.
- The rounded corners should not be visible when the sheet is fully expanded.
- Instead of snapping behavior with the notification bar, the sheet should have a smooth dragging effect. You can refer to Snapchat's bottom sheet for a better understanding of what I mean.

I have attached some screenshots for your reference.

P.S. - I'm new to Kotlin and Jetpack Compose, and I have spent a lot of time trying to fix this issue. So please bear with me and provide assistance accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Using a BottomSheet is not the preferred tool for the desired effect.
But there's a work around :

- You can change the screen layout when the bottomsheet is fully expended (you can also add an animation for it)
- Make sure to use states to control the layout changes